# Secure WordPress API, how?

Tags: rest-api, api, authentication

I'm writing a plugin that expose a custom resource via WordPress API's. Now the resource is public so anyone knows the API's endpoint can get the resource but I would to secure it, what's the best practice with WordPress?
I was thinking to JWT but I don't want to use third party plugins, maybe is it possible to use a library found on packagist.org and installed with Composer? I never did it with a WordPress plugin...

Comment: Secure for what purpose?

Comment: Why not just check to see if the requester is logged in.

Comment: The consumer for these APIs will be a Python desktop application without access to WordPress users accounts.

Comment: Have you read https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/authentication/#authentication-plugins? I don’t see why you’d want to avoid third party plugins but be ok with a third party library.